# git clone and remote dependency

Tags: python, git, github

I have my own python project (local to my laptop and no git init)
and  I want to use some module of capirca (https://github.com/google/capirca.git) so what i did was:

- Activate my venv in my own project
- **Clone** the repository: git clone https://github.com/google/capirca.git from isnide my own project
- Folder "capirca" is now inside my project

I want now to create some function inside folder Capirca/ but as soon i modify anything the modified file appear in my source-control section ready to be committed (visual-studio)

```
(vend) ➜  capirca git:(master) git remote -v                                      
origin  https://github.com/google/capirca.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/google/capirca.git (push)
```

I tried to delete the git origin

```
(venv) ➜  capirca git:(master) git remote rm origin                                   
(venv) ➜  capirca git:(master) git remote -v
```

but still, the file that i create appear in my source control (visual studio code) as ready to be committed.
This is valid for anything inside folder capirca.

What am i missing here?

Comment: there will be a hidden folder named `.git` , delete that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the expected behavior that any changes you make in a `git` repository, it will be picked up by `git`.

If you don't want this to happen, simply delete the `.git` folder inside the newly cloned repository. This will imply that you won't be able to pull any latest changes in your dependency, hence not a recommended approach.

Else if you want your folder to be tracked by `git` and the new project be ignored, you need to create a `.gitignore` file in the root of your project and add the folder you want to ignore.

The most ideal approach is to use a `submodule`.

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/org/repo
```

Any further changes in the dependency / submodule should be made in a separate branch, ideally, you can fork the dependency in your GitHub, essentially allowing you to commit your changes in your dependency as well as allowing you to pull-in any additional bug-fix or features in the mainline.

Detailed explanation for submodule here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules